# How to create custom module in odoo for creating products

Tags: xml, postgresql, python-3.x, odoo-8

I want to create a custom module for creating products in odoo v8 and i am not able to understand from where to start, as there are various tables for product. **I want to fetch data from a custom table in postgresql and from that table's data i want to create products.**

Comment: Products created are stored in 'product.template' and 'product.product' table.Why do u want to create another table now?

Comment: I am getting data from an API and from that data i want to create products having only those fields which are coming with the data. And in the existing product module it is only possible by adding new fields.